# What validation does Watson Tone Analyzer have for version query parameter?

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson, tone-analyzer

I am using the POST API for Watson Tone Analyzer. The version query parameter is required. 
https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/tone-analyzer/api/v3/tone?version=2016-05-19
This version is in the form yyyy-mm-dd. If a future date is given the API does not throw any error. Also, if 2016-09-1234 is given it still works fine instead of throwing an error. It also gives a 200OK if any random date in the correct format is given. But, if a date 2016-06 is given, it gives a bad request error.
What validation is applied by Tone Analyzer Service on the version???

Answer (score 0):

When there is any changes to the API, they release a new, dated version. The value for the version parameter is the date for the version of the API that you want to call. The current version is 2016-05-19. Check out the [Release notes](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/tone-analyzer/release-notes.html) for the changelog of available versions.

Please check out Versioning section in https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/api-guidelines#versioning to understand more about it.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that. I just want to know what validation is applied internally?? How does it validate if the date is one of the release dates?

Comment: @ShwetaJ Please checkout the link in my answer section to understand it better!